# github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go has no package path for golang version 1.18

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protoc

we are trying to build an application, but unable to generate the code using protoc-gen-go

$ make

go version go1.18 linux/amd64

/usr/local/go/bin/go

make -C go_source all

make[1]: Entering directory '/home/593m/team_name/zk/internal-pkg/go_source'
cd /home/593m/team_name/zk/internal-pkg/go_source//src/nexus.com/vendor/github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go; go install
without -mod=vendor, directory /home/593m/team_name/zk/internal-pkg/go_source/src/appnexus.com/vendor/github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go has no package path
Makefile:72: recipe for target '/home/593m/team_name/zk/internal-pkg/go_source/bin/protoc-gen-go' failed
make[1]: *** [/home/593m/team_name/zk/internal-pkg/go_source/bin/protoc-gen-go] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/593m/team_name/zk/internal-pkg/go_source''
Makefile:26: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

Make file :

$(REPOROOT)/bin/protoc-gen-go: $(REPOROOT)/src/nexus.com/vendor/github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go/*.go
cd $(REPOROOT)/src/nexus.com/vendor/github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go; $(GOINSTALL)

$(REPOROOT)/bin/generate_proto: $(REPOROOT)/bin/protoc-gen-go $(REPOROOT)/resources/proto/*
mkdir -p $(REPOROOT)/src/nexus.com/odc/odcproto                                           #######ODCPROTO gets generated in this step

Comment: Also its working fine with golang version 1.12 and issue persists only with version 1.18

Comment: the github.com url is deprecated, you should try to update and use `google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the code from make file to this code

```
CURRENT_DIR=$(shell pwd)

build:
    CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -mod=vendor -a -installsuffix cgo -o ${CURRENT_DIR}/bin/${APP} ${APP_CMD_DIR}/main.go

proto-gen:
    ./scripts/gen-proto.sh  ${CURRENT_DIR}
    ls genproto/*.pb.go | xargs -n1 -IX bash -c "sed -e '/bool/ s/,omitempty//' X > X.tmp && mv X{.tmp,}"
```